# Rendering a partial view with ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

Currently I have a main view called `getRolesByYear.cshtml`. In this view I have three buttons, each for an year. When I click a button(or on page load) I invoke a method, which takes an int 'year' for a parameter and calls an ajax with the year parameter. This ajax calls an action method (getRolesByYear, the one for the main view). The Action method makes a query to a database, a result of which is a list of `ViewModel` objects. In the return statement I return a PartialView like this : `return PartialView("_yearlyRoles",list);`. Sadly, after all this, instead of getting a list of the desired objects in my frontend, all i get is an error from  the error part of the ajax call. I am generally a novice and I am very stuck with this.

Here is the main view `getRolesByYear.cshtml`:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "getRolesByYear";
}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    getRolesForYear(parseInt(@DateTime.Now.Year));

    $(function () {
        $('#years a').click(function () {
            var year = $(this).text();
            console.log(year);
            getRolesForYear(parseInt(year));
        });
    })
    //console.log(year);


    function getRolesForYear(year) {
        console.log(year);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("getRolesByYear", "WorkRoles")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                year: year
            },
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {



                $("#partial").html(data);


        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    }



</script>

<div id = "years" class="btn-group btn-group-justified timeline">
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.Year</a>
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year</a>
    <a  href="#@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year" class="btn btn-primary">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year</a>
</div>

<div id = "partial"></div>
```

The partial view :

```
@model IEnumerable<eksp.Models.RoleViewModel>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>item.Role.RoleName</h2>

        <h1> item.Role.RoleDescription</h1>
        <p class="lead">Focus start : item.Role.FocusStart</p>
        <p>Focus end : item.Role.FocusStart </p>

    </div>
}
```

The Action Method :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getRolesByYear(int year)
    {
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();


        var list = db.WorkRoles.
            Join(db.WorkRolesUsersDetails,
            o => o.WorkRoleId, od => od.WorkRoleId,
            (o, od) => new
            {
                WorkRoleId = o.WorkRoleId,
                RoleName = o.RoleName,
                RoleDescription = o.RoleDescription,
                CompanyId = o.CompanyId,
                WRUDId = od.WRUDId,
                UserDetailsId = od.UserDetailsId,
                FocusStart = od.FocusStart,
                FocusEnd = od.FocusEnd
            }).ToList()
            .Select(item => new RoleViewModel(
               item.WorkRoleId,
                item.RoleName,
                item.RoleDescription,
                item.CompanyId,
                item.WRUDId,
                item.UserDetailsId,
                item.FocusStart,
                item.FocusEnd)).ToList();


        //RoleViewModel rv = list;

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_yearlyRoles", list);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(list);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: "all i get is an error from the error part of the ajax call." What is the error? Currently your "error" callback just swallows the real error and outputs an arbitrary string. Check the ajax docs here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for the parameters that get passed to that callback, they will allow you to report the real error. Also, all modern browser have Dev tools, most will display the ajax error in the console, and you can also check the Network tab and inspect the request itself. The HTTP status code and the error message would be useful things to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the reported error message, you need to alter your ajax call. By setting "data" parameter to "json" you're telling ajax to expect JSON-formatted data back in the response, but a partial view is HTML, so change your ajax call to reflect this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("getRolesByYear", "WorkRoles")/' + year,
    dataType: "html", //set the correct data type for the response
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

As an aside, you can improve your error handling on the client side quite straightforwardly by changing errorFunc to something like this, using the parameters that are provided to the callback by $.ajax:

```
function errorFunc(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("An error occurred while trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
}
```

For less instrusive reporting and/or easier debugging, you could change the `alert` to `console.log`. To get more detail you could also log the entire jQXHR object:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(jQXHR));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the action is able to read the parameter. I can see it's value in the debugger.

Comment: ok thanks for the update. so what's the real error then? Something going wrong in the action method?

Comment: no, by error, i mean the alert "error" which i am getting in the error: errorFunc part of the ajax call.

Comment: I know. But what is it? I've shown you how to find the real error message. Also when you run with the debugger, does it stop on any exceptions? And which "return" statement does it execute? An error in the ajax call could imply a server-side error - especially if the HTTP status is 500 ("Internal server error")

Comment: "An error occured while trying to contat the server : 200 parseerror SyntaxError : Unexpected token < in JSON at position 8"

Comment: ah of course. Change `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "html"` in your ajax definition. You're saying you're expecting JSON back but a partial view is HTML. Will update the answer

Comment: it is almost working now!  Seems that something is wrong in my partialview, because instead of the actual data i get something like item.Role.RoleName, but i have 11 jumbotrons, which is the number of the elements in the list. :)))

Comment: you missed an @: `<h2>item.Role.RoleName</h2>` needs an @ before "item" otherwise it treats it as literal text rather than a Razor command. Same for all the other fields too